# Is there a way to call 4 APIs and then create a list and draw a Pie Chart

Tags: dart, flutter

I need to call 4 APIs on a same server and then use the result to create a list and want to pass the same list to create a pie chart.

I have created a list but unable to pass that list in pie chart.

```
main() async {
 // returned dataset example:
 //  [{females: 1367341, country: Brazil, age: 18, males: 1368729, 
year: 1980, total: 2736070}]
 final age18data = await getJson(
    'http://api.population.io:80/1.0/population/2019/India/18/');
final age30data = await getJson(
  'http://api.population.io:80/1.0/population/2019/India/30/');
final age45data = await getJson(
  'http://api.population.io:80/1.0/population/2019/India/45/');
final age60data = await getJson(
  'http://api.population.io:80/1.0/population/2019/India/60/');

final values = [
age18data[0]["total"],
age30data[0]["total"],
age45data[0]["total"],
age60data[0]["total"]
```

];

I have done till here now I want to use these values list to draw the pie chart using charts_flutter package

Comment: Please provide more details like the code you have and where exactly you're stuck.

Comment: yes, there is a way. Call 4 Apis, get result info and combine them in one list and then use that list to draw a pie chart.

Comment: I want full code for this

Comment: Please i am new in coding

Comment: Getting the list is done just stuck how to use that list to draw that piw chart

Comment: Please help I am really strucked at this point

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, 4 api calls to same server, and a pie chart:

```
import "dart:math" as math;
import "dart:io";
import "dart:convert";

main() async {
  // returned dataset example:
  //  [{females: 1367341, country: Brazil, age: 18, males: 1368729, year: 1980, total: 2736070}]
  final age18data = await getJson(
      'http://api.population.io:80/1.0/population/2019/India/18/');
  final age30data = await getJson(
      'http://api.population.io:80/1.0/population/2019/India/30/');
  final age45data = await getJson(
      'http://api.population.io:80/1.0/population/2019/India/45/');
  final age60data = await getJson(
      'http://api.population.io:80/1.0/population/2019/India/60/');

  final values = [
    age18data[0]["total"],
    age30data[0]["total"],
    age45data[0]["total"],
    age60data[0]["total"]
  ];

  final allTotal = values[0] + values[1] + values[2] + values[3];

  final proportion = values.map((v) => v / allTotal).toList();

  print("Population of India:");
  print("A - 18 y.o. ${values[0]} (${proportion[0]})");
  print("B - 25 y.o. ${values[1]} (${proportion[1]})");
  print("C - 45 y.o. ${values[2]} (${proportion[2]})");
  print("D - 60 y.o. ${values[3]} (${proportion[3]})");

  final labels = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];

  asciiPieChart(labels, proportion);
}

Future<dynamic> getJson(String url) async {
  var request =
      await HttpClient().getUrl(Uri.parse(url)); // produces a request object
  var response = await request.close(); // sends the request

  var body = await response.transform(Utf8Decoder()).join("");

  return json.decode(body);
}

void asciiPieChart(dynamic k, dynamic v) {
  // adapted from javascript version:
  // https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/23351/18464
  dynamic d, y, s, x, r, a, i, f, p, t, j;

  r = 10.0;
  d = r * 2;
  p = [];
  for (y = 0; y < d; y++) {
    p.add([]);
    for (x = 0; x < d; x++) p[y].add(" ");
  }
  t = 0;
  i = -1;
  for (f = 0; f < 1; f += 1 / (r * 20)) {
    if (f > t) t += v[++i];
    a = math.pi * 2 * f;
    for (j = 0; j < r; j++) {
      int px = ((math.sin(a) * j).round() + r).toInt();
      int py = ((math.cos(a) * j).round() + r).toInt();

      p[px][py] = k[i < 0 ? k.length + i : i];
    }
  }
  s = "";
  for (y = 0; y < d; y++) {
    for (x = 0; x < d; x++) s += p[y][x];
    s += "\n";
  }

  print(s);
}
```

Run `dart example.dart` prints out:

```
Population of India:
A - 18 y.o. 25026690 (0.33671242865945705)
B - 25 y.o. 22643410 (0.30464746133954734)
C - 45 y.o. 16325200 (0.21964142043359983)
A - 60 y.o. 10331300 (0.13899868956739578)

       CCCCCCC
     CCCCCCCCCCC
    CCCCCCCCCCCCD
   BBCCCCCCCCCCDDD
  BBBBCCCCCCCCDDDDD
  BBBBBCCCCCCDDDDDD
 BBBBBBBCCCCCDDDDDDD
 BBBBBBBCCCDDDDDDDDD
 BBBBBBBBCCDDDDDDDDD
 BBBBBBBBBDDDDDDDDDD
 BBBBBBBBBAAAAAAAAAA
 BBBBBBBBBAAAAAAAAAA
 BBBBBBBBAAAAAAAAAAA
  BBBBBBAAAAAAAAAAA
  BBBBBBAAAAAAAAAAA
   BBBBAAAAAAAAAAA
    BBBAAAAAAAAAA
     BAAAAAAAAAA
       AAAAAAA
```

You can of-course apply same ideas and use different charting method for example as described in
https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/example/pie_charts/donut.html

Doing http requests also is easier with https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/http

Comment: But I want the answer using the package

Comment: Can you do this with charts_flutter package....I am really confused on how to put the list to draw the pie chart

Comment: I understood the API calling and formation of list....But stuck in to use that list for drawing pie chart.....Can you please do it with chart_flutter library for drawing graph...

Comment: @newprogrammer unfortunately it's very hard to help you as I have no knowledge about what you have tried and what doesn't work.

Comment: I have reached till the final values as per your example ....Now I just want to use these values to draw the pie chart...Here I am facing problem